# Disable Gallary View Swipe

Tags: android, galleryview

Currently I am using gallery View and using its Swipe effect that is working perfectly fine Using base Adapter.
But i have changed Scenario
i want to change image in gallery View on click button left and click button right 
and want to disable the Swipe view of Gallery 
i m using base adapter code for base Adapter is as following

```
 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context ctx;
        int imageBackground;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            ctx = c;
            //TypedArray ta = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
            //imageBackground = ta.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 1);
            //ta.recycle();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return pics.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {

            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {

            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            galaryBg= new ImageView(ctx);

            galaryBg.setImageResource(pics[arg0]);
            galaryBg.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            galaryBg.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150,150));
            //galaryBg.setBackgroundResource(imageBackground);


            return galaryBg;
        }

    }
```

and my Button Movement are following

```
     public void moveScreen(View v)
 {      
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.dummy_leftnavBtn:
              int position = mGallery.getSelectedItemPosition() - 1;
              if (position < 0)
                  return;
             checkIfonStart(position);
             checkIfonEnd(position);
             getStringWithPositon(position);
             mGallery.setSelection(position);
              break;
          case R.id.dummy_rightnavBtn:
              position = mGallery.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1;
              if (position >= mGallery.getCount())
                  return;
              checkIfonEnd(position);
              checkIfonStart(position);
              getStringWithPositon(position);
              mGallery.setSelection(position);
              break;
        }

 }
```

now i need to disable the Gallery Swipe need help 
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Solution 
for this I just override the  `onTouchListener` and return always true 
and that worked for me